# Can we put 2 flot chart in the same line?

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

Is it possible to do as in image by flot.js?

[Flot 2 graphs in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZMc4.png)

Normally, when call below code, first and second graphs will automatically have new line.

```
<div id="flotcontainer1"></div>
<div id="flotcontainer2"></div>
```

Comment: You could add `style="display:inline; float:left;"` in you div

Comment: @StergiosMarias `inline` doesn't work, you have to use `inline-block`.

Comment: @Raidri I was talking about the example with 2 divs [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpgxxab9/2/)

Comment: @StergiosMarias sorry for the misunderstanding. `inline` works together with `float: left`, only `inline-block` works without the `float`

Comment: Thank you Stergios Marias and Raidri :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place multiple flot charts beside each other, you can use CSS styling (`display: inline-block`), see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpgxxab9/) for a full example. You can use absolute or relative `width` depending you your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help Raidri :)